# Create Geokit bounds from many points

Tags: geokit

Is there a simple way to create a Geokit bounds that encompasses a number of points and/or polygons?  I have an application where disjoint groups of polygons form a logical unit and I want to know 'does any part of this logical unit lie on my map'?  I could do this by working through all the elements but it would be simpler if on sub-object creation I can update a parent-object bounds object.

Comment: To clarify something, the points and/or polygons are associated with sub-objects.  Think something like 'There is a town, and the town has 5 parks.  If I know the boundaries of each of the 5 parks, I can assign them each a Bounds.  Now how do I take these 5 Bounds objects and combine them to create a Bounds object that encompasses the town, or at least the town as defined by its parks?'

Comment: OK, in case anyone wants to do this...

Comment: did you get the solution for this?